# Over By Partition Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some issues with Over Partition by. I am trying to get:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwy1f.jpg)

The inventory ordered column is the problem using this code:

```
select     
l.whseloc,l.invtid,        
l.qty,     
case when f.MRPFlag= 0 then 'NON-Usable' else 'Usable' end as NetStatus,      

SUM(p.qtyord-p.qtyrcvd) over (Partition by l.invtid) as InventoryOrdered,
SUM(l.qty*f.mrpflag)over(partition by l.invtid) as TotalNet 
from location l (nolock)  
join inventory i (nolock) on l.invtid=i.invtid  
join loctable f (nolock) on l.whseloc=f.whseloc   
left join [dbo].[opspurord] p (nolock) on l.InvtID=p.InvtID
```

What am I doing wrong?

[First Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzKB5.jpg)

Comment: your "first try" and "desired result" are the same image.

Comment: I have entered a suggested edit that fixes the image tag, but you need to add in your expected results image as well.

Comment: My bad I put in the correct images.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: It looks like your data is exactly 7 times your desired results - it may be a join issue.  But as mentioned before, it's hard to tell without sample data

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information (no sample data) in the question to tell you where you have gone wrong, so I will describe how to debug and fix the problem.

Display `PARTITION BY` columns and aggregated columns in your result set as separate columns, while keeping everything else the same.

```
select l.whseloc, l.invtid, l.qty,     
    case when f.MRPFlag= 0 then 'NON-Usable' else 'Usable' end as NetStatus,      
    SUM(p.qtyord-p.qtyrcvd) over (Partition by l.invtid) as InventoryOrdered,
    p.qtyord-p.qtyrcvd AS InventoryOrderedRowSUM
    SUM(l.qty*f.mrpflag)over(partition by l.invtid) as TotalNet,
    l.qty*f.mrpflag AS TotalNetRowSUM
from location l (nolock)
...
ORDER BY l.invtid -- Add Order BY to make it easier to analyse data
```

`l.invtid` - this will show you groups of rows which summed by `SUM` function
`InventoryOrderedRowSUM` - shows you the value produced for each row. If you manually add up these values for a given `l.invtid` you should get the same result as `InventoryOrdered`.

Where to go from here:

By looking at the individual `InventoryOrderedRowSUM` you should be able to tell what combination of these values gives you the desired result. Once you have this worked out, you can adjust your `InventoryOrdered` function. If this is not obvious, then you need repeat the above process while adding `p.qtyord` and `p.qtyrcvd` to the result set.

I suspect that `InventoryOrdered` should just be `p.qtyord-p.qtyrcvd` (no `SUM` needed) based on the fact that 11200 is divisible by 1600.